# How do I pass a selectbox variable to the View from the Controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, variables

I want to pass a variable (selectbox id, which comes from database) to the view from the controller, but do not know how to do it.

Comment: Please elaborate with code.

Comment: Can you clean up your question please?  You're asking how to pass a variable "**FROM** the view **TO** the controller", but in your comments, you're asking about the exact opposite, passing a variable **to** the view **from** the controller.

Comment: Based on comments and answer, you don't know the difference between "to" and "from". Edited.  You also could have easily solved this yourself by doing the very straightforward CI tutorials and examples contained in their thorough documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original question wasn't that clear, but after reading the comments you could do this.

Controller

```
//whatever function you're using to populate your original array below.
$data['all'] = $this->model_name->getData();
//then run that data through a foreach loop to populate the dropdown variable.
foreach($data['all'])
{
    $data['idDropDown'][$data['all']['id']]=$data['all']['ad'];
}
```

This will pass an array like: [455]=>Aliağa, [456]=>Balçova to the view as $idDropDown along with your original data as $all

Then in the view just used CI's form dropdown.

```
echo form_dropdown('id',$idDropDown);
```

Comment: Reading both his question and title, he says he wants to send it FROM view TO controller.  Your answer shows the opposite.

Comment: If you'd seen the comments, that were there yesterday you'd see this is what he was trying to accomplish, for some reason the comments were deleted.

Comment: Well considering it was apparently the right answer down voting it may have been a mistake ;)

Comment: Not really and don't temp me.  ;)  I've down-voted accepted answers in the past when they've had nothing to do with the OP, they contain technical errors, or just earned a down-vote for any other reason.  (Obviously, it's not a mistake or the system wouldn't allow it.) In this case, I've edited the OP so that your answer makes more sense.  The OP also earns a close vote for a poorly written & researched question and a down-vote for not caring enough to clean it up himself.

Comment: So you downvote because you decide an answer isn't worthy rather than actually looking. Just because the OP wasn't 100% clear doesn't change the fact that the answer is correct and coded properly. Don't tempt me? This isn't a child's game on the play ground, we're supposed to be here to help, not make arguments and votes based on semantics.

Comment: Relax man... stop and think a bit more about what I did here and what I wrote.  I never said I don't look before I down-vote.  Answers have to be **relevant** to questions or this whole "question and answer" thing is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a controller called **article** and a method **index** then in your view you will have :

```
<?php 
echo form_open('article/index');
echo form_input('text');
echo form_close;
?>
```

And in your controller something like:

```
public function index() 
{
   if($this->input->post()) { 
      $this_is_catched_text = $_POST['text'];
   }
}
```

This is without validation and other stuff. Just you get the idea how it works.

Comment: controller/index or article/index ?

Comment: It should be  `article/index` , sorry

Comment: i sent $data to view and it contains a lot of variable ( array in array ) something like this Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 455 [il_id] => 35 [ad] => Aliağa ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 456 [il_id] => 35 [ad] => Balçova )  i just want to create dropdown with id and ad  how will i do?

Comment: foreach($ilce as $x)
{
 $drop_down .= array('id'=>$x['id'], 'ad' => $x['ad']);

} it gives error

Comment: selectbox is e.g. `echo form_dropdown('names', $list');` where `$list = array('0' => 'James', '1' => 'John', '2' => 'David');`

Answer (score 0):

In your case it will be like this

```
$ilce = array(array("id" => 455, "il_id" => 35,"ad" => "Aliağa"), 
              array("id" => 456, "il_id" => 35, "ad" => "Balçova"));

$options = array();

foreach($ilce as $x) {
    $options[$x['id']] = $x['ad']; 
} 

echo form_dropdown('names', $options);
```

Comment: Reading both his question and title, he says he wants to send it FROM view TO controller.  Your answer shows the opposite.

Comment: Maybe, but in one of comment he wrote "i just want to create dropdown with id and ad how will i do?" he asked a question not quite true I mean

Comment: I agree and that's why I did not down-vote you.  Although his question is clearly written, he still may be confused about what he wrote.

Comment: Andrei, thank you, you told me right, its exactly what i want. by the way, i will create selectbox without using form helper, because i can't find giving id with form_dropdown to selectbox..